# Integrating community plugins into a ready Eclipse RCP app?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, pydev

I already have a standalone Eclipse RCP application. The next task is to integrate the plugins which are widely used in the Eclipse community like **CDT** or say **PyDev** to provide the editing and debugging facilities in respective programming languages inside the already developed RCP app. Just wondering how do i go about accomplishing this task. Should i start with playing around the extension points of the plugins and adding it to the **MANIFEST.MF** ?

What are the various ways of achieving this ? Which one to pick over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing you should consider (besides the technical) is a conceptional.

Plugins like CDT are making a lot of assumptations about their environment they are integrated into. That means your RCP should have a very similar user-interface and behavior like the normal Eclipse SDK so that the integration of other "IDE-ish" plugins is not a break of the interface principles of your RCP.

If your RCP is not based on a common navigator, projects, files (in general the Workspace) and several editors the integration of Plugins like CDT will be a nightmare for your users and will feel like another application within your RCP.

Make also sure that ui-contributions from third-party-plugins are visible (e.g. if the third-party-plugin is contributing a preference page, make sure that your RCP has the menu-item to open the preference-window)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to load the new features/plugins in your existing RCP application. For this you have to adapt your product definition and load the new feature.xml files. or you enhance your own feature.xml and place the new plugins into.

Afterwards you have to decide, whether the new functions/view/perspectives are contributions to an already existing RCP extension point and whether you use this extension point in your RCP product.

If you want to use the new functions in another way (because the default is not enough) you have to point to specific views/actions in the new plugins and call them by your self. Fot his you have to adapt the MANIFEST.MF of your own plugin and point to the new plugins. If you do it, you can not switch off the added features, because you do have a jard link to these plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Your RCP product already depends on the RCP feature (org.eclipse.rcp) or a subset of its plug-ins. This means, it already includes the plug-ins defining the [basic extension points](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/index.html).

To include functionality (extensions) from additional features, just add these features to your product configuration dependencies. For example, you would have to add the feature org.eclipse.cdt  for CDT and org.python.pydev.feature for PyDev.

The hard part begins when you need to include only some of the features' plug-ins.

You'll have to isolate the plug-in(s) providing the functionality you require.
For UI contributions, you can use the plug-in selection spy by selecting the required UI part and clicking alt+shift+F1.
For non-UI contributions, information for contributed extensions can be found in the plugin.xml files in the plug-in sources.

These plug-ins, along with their dependencies can be added to a custom feature, which can be included in your product.

Although dated, the article [Building a CDT-based editor](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-cdt1/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX44&S_CMP=EDU) might also be of help.